# How to change edition of SQL 2012 from express to standard

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2012

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard that is running  SQL 2012 Express.

How do I go about changing it to be SQL 2012 Standard?

I have the media (and ISO image) and it is currently mounted.

I have done some research, but can only find info about upgrades from previous versions of SQL like 2008, but about changing from express to standard in the same version.

Looking at the SQL Server Installation Center there is a section under Maintenance called Edition Upgrade. Is this what I need?

I am doing this to clean a mess left by my predecessor. I inherited this system and am trying to get it off express.

Comment: The process should be identical.  What makes you think it isn't the same as previous versions?

Comment: I've not done this in previous versions. All I found is upgrading from a previous version. Not changing the edition. I only need to change the edition from express to standard not upgrade the version.

Comment: I will ask again, what makes you think the process has changed, it hasn't change.  You did it with previous versions, do it again, exactly the way you did it with previous versions

Comment: I just said that I've not done this with previous versions. I've never changed from express to standard before.

Comment: You indicated the following, "I have done some research, but can only find info about upgrades from previous versions of SQL like 2008, but about changing from express to standard in the same version.", have you tried following the information you found.  **By the way, before you get upset and think i am not listening, I simply misread your response comment as you had done this before.**  The first guide/directions I found, by doing a google search, are applicable to any version of SQL Server by the way.

Comment: [Bing search results](https://www.bing.com/search?q=sql+express+to+standard&FORM=AWRE)

Comment: Well, it wasn't the first link, but the second is not one that came up in any of my previous searches. Though it's for 2008, it looks like it will work.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the help! That was exactly it.

Comment: Run SQL Server Installation Center, then go to Maintenance > Edition Upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this as the answer only because @Ramhound has not done so. If he wants the points he can post and I'll change the accepted answer.

What I ended up doing was following this [post](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/vault-products/troubleshooting/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Vault-Install/files/GUID-D17881EB-0D1D-4544-92C0-2F8F671AF94A-htm.html) as it walks through changing the edition of SQL 2008 Express to a full version of SQL 2008. Although I am using SQL 2012 the steps were the same.

1. Run the full version of SQL setup application.
2. Select Maintenance > Edition Upgrade
3. Select the SQL instance and start the upgrade.
4. After the upgrade is complete, apply the latest SQL service packs since this upgrade does not include them when transferring from SQL Express

After the upgrade is complete, apply the latest SQL service pack since this upgrade actually does not have on and it is not transferred from SQL Express.